How to migrate current Ubuntu 24.04 installation from an SSD to a different SSD with windows dual-boot?
I have two SSD, SSD1 with Ubuntu 23.10 and windows, and a new SSD I added to try Ubuntu 24.04 (SSD2). I can boot with grub on windows, old ubuntu 23.10 or new 24.04 (Installed on SSD2) But with the time, I tried 24.04 enough. It works fine and now I don't use old ubuntu 23.10 anymore, so want to migrate my Ubuntu 24.04 installation from SSD2 to SSD1, keeping windows, and delete Ubuntu 24.04 from SSD2 to use all the space there to store videos, photos, movies, etc.
What I did for now, was delete Ubuntu 23.01 partitions from SSD1, backup Ubuntu 24.04 partitions from SSD2 and restore to SSD1 with clonecilla, keeping windows partitions. I didn't delete Ubuntu 24.04 partitions from SSD2 yet.
Now, after update grub, I can boot on windows and Ubuntu 24.04, old 23.10 isn't showed anymore on boot, but Ubuntu 24.04 boot on SSD2, not SSD1 as I want.
So, in a word, the question is, how can I migrate my current Ubuntu 24.04 installation from SSD2 to SSD1, keeping my windows installation?
Thanks

Ok, I tried deleting the SSD2 ubuntu partitions, and now it boot fine from SSD1.

Since you cloned the partition from SSD 2 into SSD 1, both original and the cloned partitions had the same UUID used in the fstab to refer to the Ubuntu system partition. It is like 2 people in the room with the same name. When you call out the name, you didn't know who will answer.

This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - From Review
